What to do with checkout pages that are on different non-controlled domains?
I've recently implemented Google Tag Manager Server Side on a site that uses a 3rd party for checkout.
The checkout uses 2 domains outside of our control and not on the domains set to our GTM Server Side container. The approximate flow is:

User browses pages on our-domain.com and clicks to the checkout.
User starts the checkout process on 3rd-party-checkout.com .
User completes the purchase on 3rd-party-payment-gateway.com .
User is directed back to confirmation page back on 3rd-party-checkout.com.

Only our-domain.com is within our control and set to GTM Server Side.
When in Preview Mode on the client container I can see all events independent of domain being sent to the server container. Events originating on our-domain.com are visible in Server Side Preview Mode but no events are visible for the latter 2 domains.
Likewise those events from our-domain.com are visible in GA4, purchase events through the process are not visible if using server-side instrumentation, but are visible using client-side instrumentation.
Is there a way to ensure purchase events are visible using GTM Server Side given the above domain limitations?

You have two containers - front-end and back-end, and all the FE container does is it uses the BE container as a mirror for tracking? Is there a reason for sGTM? Seems to me like it's just an overengineered solution.
But also, when you inspect the network requests the FE GTM sends to sGTM, do you see the difference in responses between your site versus the third party site? The obvious problem in this setup would, of course, be cross-domain tracking, but it doesn't explain why you don't see any hits sent from the third party. You would still get the hits, it's just the sessions would be broken.
Check your sGTM setup. Maybe you're filtering out any requests by the document location field or something to that akin. In that case you'd not see any suspicious in the network tab, but you would also see no events in GA.
